# WP7 Link to Buy App/Reviews

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I have seen in some applications they link directly to the Review page of their application. It also states [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967551%28VS.92%29.aspx) that developers should "Provide a way for users to buy your trial application before the end-of-trial."

Does anyone have any information how I can do either of these? I'm guessing it's just a link to the market place I can launch from my app.

Answer (score 1):

You answered yourself you just launch your app page in the marketplace.

If you don't know how to do that here's an example:

```
 MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();

 marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = yourappidonthestore;
 marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;

 marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```